# Where does the log goes when error_logger:info_msg/2 is used

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm using Erlang  and Chicagoboss. When I am connected to localhost, I can see the log in server console. Where I run `sh init-dev.sh`.But in production mode I guess project runs as a daemon. Does anyone know where I can see the logs written by the statement `error_logger:info_msg/2`.

```
error_logger:info_msg(" SomeVaraiable : - ", [SomeVaraiable]),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see them in `log/console.log`. Try:

```
tail -f log/console.og
```

Also, `error_logger` takes format string similar to `io:format`. To print your variable it is best to use:

```
error_logger:info_msg("SomeVaraiable = ~p.", [SomeVaraiable]),
```

Your version would cause "FORMAT ERROR". `~p` formatter is like "pretty print" and you have to have one for each Variable in the list, that is second argument to `info_msg`. I also like displaying variables for debugging purpose in format:

```
Variable = actual_content_of_variable.
```

Because this way, I am able to copy them from logs and paste it to Erlang console to do some further investigation (it is mostly useful in development mode, though).

Answer (score 1):

error_logger is a part of sasl application. So you need to check your sys.config and find sasl settings there..

Comment: True, but CB uses lager, which logs also error_logger messages. Its configured in boss.config and by default it points to "log/console.log", so you don't have to worry about sasl settings.